# My camera pointer is returning null when accessing the camera anywhere else but the constructor

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to send out a ray that starts from the camera location to a certain distance away. This is for a "gun" that i'm making. When I try to access the camera anywhere else but the constructor I get a camera is null.

When I ran the debugger the camera returns to null before it reaches the first "BeginPlay" function. The `CameraSpringArm` stays attatched to the object though.

I've tried rearranging around the functions and the pointers in the header file but I still stuck.

cpp:

```
 #include "MyCharacter.h"

// Sets default values
AMyCharacter::AMyCharacter()
{
 ThirdPerson = 2;
 FirstPerson = 1;

 // Set this character to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off 
 to improve performance if you don't need it.
 PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;
 // Create a first person camera component.
 CameraSpringArm = CreateDefaultSubobject<USpringArmComponent> 
 (TEXT("CameraSpringArm"));

 CharacterCamera = 
 CreateDefaultSubobject<UCameraComponent(TEXT("FirstPersonCamera"));

 // Attach the camera component to our capsule component.
 CameraSpringArm->SetupAttachment(RootComponent);
 CharacterCamera->SetupAttachment(CameraSpringArm);

 // Allow the pawn to control camera rotation.
 CharacterCamera->bUsePawnControlRotation = true;
 SwitchCamera(CharacterCamera, CameraSpringArm, ThirdPerson);

 bPressedCameraSwap = false;
 bFire = false;
}


 // Called to bind functionality to input
void AMyCharacter::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* 
 PlayerInputComponent)
 {
 Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(PlayerInputComponent);

 PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("MoveForward", this, 
 &AMyCharacter::MoveForward);

 PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("MoveSide", this, &AMyCharacter::MoveSide);

 PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("TurnUp", this, 
 &AMyCharacter::AddControllerYawInput);

 PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("TurnSide", this, 
 &AMyCharacter::AddControllerPitchInput);

 PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("CameraSwap", IE_Pressed, this, 
 &AMyCharacter::CameraSwap);

 PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("CameraSwap", IE_Released, this, 
 &AMyCharacter::CameraSwapStop);

 PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("Fire", IE_Pressed, this, 
 &AMyCharacter::Fire);
 }

void AMyCharacter::Fire()
 {
 bFire = true;
 float Distance = 1000.0f;
 FHitResult HitResult;
 FVector StartTrace = CharacterCamera->GetComponentLocation(); //Its 
 breaking here
 FVector ForwardVector = CharacterCamera->GetForwardVector();
 FVector EndTrace = ((ForwardVector * Distance) + StartTrace);
 FCollisionQueryParams TraceParams;

 GetWorld()->LineTraceSingleByChannel(HitResult, StartTrace, EndTrace, 
 ECC_Visibility, TraceParams);
 DrawDebugLine(GetWorld(), StartTrace, EndTrace,FColor(255,0,0), true);

 }
```

Header

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "EngineGlobals.h"
#include "Engine/Engine.h"
#include "Components/InputComponent.h"
#include "GameFramework/CharacterMovementComponent.h"
#include "Camera/CameraComponent.h"
#include "GameFramework/Controller.h"
#include "GameFramework/Character.h"
#include "GameFramework/SpringArmComponent.h"
#include "DrawDebugHelpers.h"
#include "MyCharacter.generated.h"


UCLASS()
class LEARNING_API AMyCharacter : public ACharacter
{
GENERATED_BODY()

public:
// Sets default values for this character's properties
AMyCharacter();

protected:
// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void BeginPlay() override;


public: 
// Called every frame
void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

// Called to bind functionality to input
void SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* 
PlayerInputComponent) override;

UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere)
    UCameraComponent* CharacterCamera;
UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere)
    USpringArmComponent* CameraSpringArm;
UPROPERTY()
    bool bPressedCameraSwap;
UPROPERTY()
    bool bFirstPersonEnabled{};
UPROPERTY()
    bool bThirdPersonEnabled{};
UPROPERTY()
    bool bFire;
protected:
UFUNCTION()
    void MoveForward(float Val);
//handles strafing
UFUNCTION()
    void MoveSide(float Val);
//Handles swaping camera on press
UFUNCTION()
    void CameraSwap();
//Clears swaping camera Flag
UFUNCTION()
    void CameraSwapStop();

UFUNCTION()
    void Fire();
UFUNCTION()
    void FireStop();
```

Comment: Looks like it is time to break out the debugger, and instrument the code to see what is happening why-and-where.  (Note: I did not downvote.)

Answer (score 1):

The answer was a pretty nasty bug that is present in Unreal. I had to change the name of the CharacterCamera variable. I think it was because I edited the string in the "CreateDefaultSubobject" function.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CharacterCamera` is a pointer, not an actual object. So inside the constructor you're setting `AMyCharacter.CharacterCamera` to the address of a temporary object, and when the scope of the constructor ends that temporary object gets deconstructed and the pointer becomes invalid.

There are several ways to solve this, one would be to change `CharacterCamera` to be an actual `UCameraComponent`, not just a pointer.

Another solution would be to instantiate the `UCameraComponent` outside of your function so it doesn't get deconstructed at the end of your constructor.

Comment: Wouldn't that also send the "CameraSpringArm" out of scope? It isn't when I debugged it.

Comment: Not necessarily. I can't say for sure without more context, but there are plenty of ways it could be staying in scope (the line `CameraSpringArm->SetupAttachment(RootComponent);` is most suspect. RootComponent isn't defined anywhere in here, so it must be based on a larger scope, and your CameraSpringArm somehow gets tied to it via SetupAttachment?).

Either way - CharacterCamera holds a valid address in the constructor and gets invalidated when the constructor ends. The object it's referencing is definitely going out of scope.